# Video playback not working on site pages

Tags: jquery, html

I have a section of the web site that plays a video in the background, it works fine on the homepage but when I copy the code onto another page it doesn't play the video and just shows a grey background. Not quite sure what is going on?

Here is the HTML & jQuery:-

```
<div id="whyus"></div><section class=" vc_custom_1405197800280  general-row"  >
        <div class="wpb_column col-md-12">

    <div id="videobgfull">
        <div class="videooverlay">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="general-title">
            <h2>5 reasons why you should choose UKCCTV Installations</h2>
            <hr>
            <p class="lead">&nbsp;</p>
        </div><!-- end general title -->

        <div class="custom-services">
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 first">
    <div class="ch-item">   
        <div class="ch-info-wrap">
            <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-4x"></i>
                    <h3>Expert CCTV Advisors</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                    <p>Industry professional staff to understand your scenario in detail and advise the most ideal solution that is suitable to your needs and fits the budget</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end ch-info -->
        </div><!-- end ch-info-wrap -->
    </div><!-- end ch-item -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="ch-item">   
        <div class="ch-info-wrap">
            <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-4x"></i>
                    <h3>Attention to Detail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                    <p>Our business processes follow approach of leaving no stone unturned, from planning your system to getting it installed</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end ch-info -->
        </div><!-- end ch-info-wrap -->
    </div><!-- end ch-item -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="ch-item">   
        <div class="ch-info-wrap">
            <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front">
                    <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-4x"></i>
                    <h3>Highly Qualified Engineers</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                    <p>UK's most sought after team of highly qualified engineers with industry expertise enables us to set and maintain very high standards</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end ch-info -->
        </div><!-- end ch-info-wrap -->
    </div><!-- end ch-item -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="ch-item">   
        <div class="ch-info-wrap">
            <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front">
                    <i class="fa fa-star-half-o fa-4x"></i>
                    <h3>No compromise on Quality</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                    <p>A no compromise on quality approach ensures that our solutions are more robust, user-friendly and last for years and years running</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end ch-info -->
        </div><!-- end ch-info-wrap -->
    </div><!-- end ch-item -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 last">
    <div class="ch-item">   
        <div class="ch-info-wrap">
            <div class="ch-info">
                <div class="ch-info-front">
                    <i class="fa fa-group fa-4x"></i>
                    <h3>Unrivalled Customer Care</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ch-info-back">
                    <p>As completey 'customer centered' philosophy where needs and preferences of the customer are put first and everything else after</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end ch-info -->
        </div><!-- end ch-info-wrap -->
    </div><!-- end ch-item -->
</div>
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(cash) {
         var $ = jQuery;
      var Video_back = new video_background($("#videobgfull"), { 
       "position": "absolute", //Stick within the div
       "z-index": "-1",  //Behind everything
       "loop": true,    //Loop when it reaches the end
       "autoplay": true,  //Autoplay at start
       "muted": true,   //Muted at start
       "youtube": "hT6eSm-UhiM", //Youtube video id
       "start": 5,     //Start with 6 seconds offset (to pass the introduction in this case for example)
       "video_ratio": 1.7778,   // width/height -> If none provided sizing of the video is set to adjust
       "fallback_image": "videos/main.jpg", //Fallback image path
      });
     });
</script>
```

You can see it working here:

```
http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/
```

and not working here:

```
http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/product/1-camera-residential-system-hi-res/
```

Answer (score 0):

`...new video_background(...` is not in the HTML source of the second url and I'm almost sure that's the problem :)

Comment: I've tried adding the jQuery code within the php file that has being including, in the header file, and on the page itself but neither is showing?

Comment: I just use Chrome F12 tab and see that the .js for video_background is included, but the class is never newed on  the second url. So there is an error on the server-side.

Comment: Okay @Woter Huysentruit - what is it I need to change / add on the second URL then?

Comment: I don't know, because it will be a problem in the PHP files I guess, which is a totally different question :)